# "System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80090308): The token supplied to the function is invalid" when TLS13 is enabled

Tags: c#, .net, windows, .net-core, tls1.3

After adding the below registry key to enable TLS1.3 on Windows Server 2022

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.3\Client]
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000
"Enabled"=dword:00000001
```

The .NET Client application throws the below exception

```
System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed, see inner exception.
 ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80090308): The token supplied to the function is invalid
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter, Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, Boolean isApm)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslClientAuthenticationOptions)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(String targetHost, X509CertificateCollection clientCertificates, SslProtocols enabledSslProtocols, Boolean checkCertificateRevocation)
```

Is there anything i am missing? In the .NET Client application i had set the protocol version to TLS13.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you the server or the client? Check that the server & Client has a matching cipher

Comment: Client. I did check the cipher and both have a matching cipher

Comment: is server only configured to 1.3 only? What version of .net are u on?

Comment: @Alander: Yes,i am using .NET 6 and i had tried with .NET Framework as well which is giving a different exception altogether

Comment: What authentication are you using? Certificate?

Comment: Did you check the server can support tls1.3? 
However it is only supported on newer Window's OS versions (windows 11 and server 2022+),

Answer (score 0):

Try the below before you call the server if server is also on windows 2022+

Otherwise it will not work if server is not 2022+

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls13
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Even after setting the SecurityPRotocol to Tls13 i get the same exception

Comment: it says authentication fails, how are you authenticating to the server?